# Reason for the final paragraph in Kettu's "The Midwife"

Tags: finnish-language, katja-kettu, the-midwife

Katja Kettu’s novel *The Midwife* opens with a foreword, explaining the framing device used for the story. We are told that the story was compiled by one Helena Angelhurst from diary entries, radio messages and witness accounts that were found in a wooden chest “ornately decorated in the Kurbits style”. The novel thus claims itself to be an authentic historical account (while in reality, of course, being a work of fiction written by Kettu).

We then move to the story itself and learn about the origin of the chest. When the story concludes there is an Epilogue. Various plot details are tied up, we find out that the “Helena Angelhurst” is the granddaughter of the protagonist of the work (the midwife, “Wild-Eye”), and then the final paragraph reads:

> A few other facts about the deceased, my grandfather Johannes
> Angelhurst’s beloved, and the protagonist of his story are worthy of
> note.  The Rovaniemi parish registers of 1908, the assumed year of her
> birth, show no record of a girl of that name and there is no mention
> of a nurse meeting her description in the archives of the Petsamo
> field hospital during the years of the Winter War 1939 - 1940. Neither
> is there any mention of her in the records of the Red Cross or the
> Lotta Svard auxiliary organization for women.

The final paragraph seems to indicate that there is no independent evidence for Wild-Eye’s existence. This seems to completely undercut the framing device. It can hardly be a historical account if the central character didn't actually exist. What was Kettu’s purpose in including this paragraph? It would seem that the novel would conclude perfectly well (maybe even better, and certainly more consistently) in its absence.

Comment: It reminds me of the end of The Borrowers. The reader is left in doubt whether it was actually real, or just a story presented as truth to the narrator.